# What is the method of creating a skin menu?

Tags: asp.net, css

I want to develop a custom skin or a css for ASP default menu.

I want my menu look like the custom controls that are available for purchase like [Rad from Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx).

If have tried to google for CSS properties of the ASP Menu but have found only some expose properties. Would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a question of CSS markup + graphics design.
See simple css tutor:
[Creating Navigation Menus with CSS](http://www.justskins.com/css-designs/creating-navigation-menus-with-css/480)
Now, design video:
[How to create a web 2.0 menu bar in Photoshop](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to/video/how-to-create-a-web-2-0-menu-bar-in-photoshop-242144/)
Deep design tutor:
[Tutzor web 2.0 style design](http://www.tutzor.com/index.php/2008/05/tutzor-web-20-style-re-design/)

Now, talking about ASP.NET + CSS, try [ASP.NET 2.0 CSS Friendly Control Adapters](http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/WalkThru/WalkThrough.aspx)